# Install fontcustom/fontforge in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, fontforge

I'm trying to install fontforge --with-python in Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I did this hand steps listed here (https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/blob/master/INSTALL-git.md) but it still does not working.

Does someone know if there is another way to make it works?

Thanks!

Comment: You should add the specific error that you're seeing so that we can help debug it.

Comment: It was not giving me any error, but I found a better solution! I will post it at the answer box below. Tks dude!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to compile FontForge, but the Python bindings must be specifically installed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fontforge/fontforge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontforge python-fontforge
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was:

INSTALL LINUXBREW:
https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew

Then I did:

```
$brew install fontforge --with-python
$brew install eot-utils
$gem install fontcustom
```

And did the rest of my process till Gulp:

```
$npm install
$bundle install
$gulp fontcustom
$gulp
```

That is it! Tks!